# no-unused-vars eslint for property in createReducer

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have the following file:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';
import { createReducer } from 'redux-immutablejs';
import { createAction } from '../utils/Action';

const increment = createAction('INCREMENT');

const initialState = Map({
  count: 0
});

export default createReducer(initialState, {
  [increment]: (state) => {
    return state.merge({
      count: state.get('count') + 1
    });
  }
});
```

But I am getting the following eslint error:

> 3:8  error  'increment' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Or is there anyway I can disable it for this file or variable only?

I cannot get the syntax right for this.

I have tried:

```
const increment = createAction('INCREMENT'); //eslint-disable-line
```

And also:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
...
/* eslint-enable no-unused-vars */
```

And also:

```
/* eslint no-unused-vars: 0 */
```

At the top of the file

But nothing works

Comment: Are you sure the error is in that file? because eslint is saying that the error is in line 3 column 8 and in that line you have defined `import { createAction } from '../utils/Action';`

Comment: `/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/` is the correct syntax. Also, what version of eslint are you using? 3.10.2 seems to detect computed property usage.

Answer (score 2):

May be, you need to install eslint-plugin-react and enable rules

```
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "error",
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error"
```